# best landing page CTA placement (best practises)

Tags: conversion, placement, landing-page, cta

We are building a landing page for buy box report where we want user to fill out the form as priority and so we kept the cta in each section. click on cta it again goes to top section to fill out the form.

Is this a good UX? I feel it will be irritating.

so i came up with a solution of adding email field in the bottom of the page and clicking on "get started" goes to the form again. we dont want add pop-up.

Please let me know if you have any better solution.[image]

Comment: It could be collapsed to a bar on scroll-down and stuck to the top to be always visible.

Comment: This question seems to expand your other question (https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/132083/form-field-in-a-landing-page). You might consider combining them?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! I don't really know what to answer - you're asking for mini-reviews of two designs - which one to discuss? Also, site rules say we don't do reviews here... Maybe you can reformulate or break down the question. I wonder, for example, *why* you "dont want [to] add [a] pop-up"? And I have no idea what a "buy box report" is - but maybe irrelevant to your question.

Comment: I am asking best practises for this kind of scenarios. @virtualnobi

Answer (score 1):

When we want to design and improve the UX of landing pages, we use a concept which is called AIDA. AIDA stands for Attention, Interest, Desire, and Action. This flow based on the idea that a visitor progresses thought a series of leaner steps on their way to making to take the action.

- Attention. In this section, basically you capture the attention of your user/visitor with a hight relevant and powerful headline.
- Interest. You can present your product or your service in the form of photo of video. It is very attractive.
- Desire. This is created through the use of benefits and of course the features that appeal to the needs of your visitor.
- Action. Finally, a strong call-to-action completes your story and the point where your visitor has been convinced that your solution is appropriate for exactly their needs.

Your aim is to prompt visitors to do one action you want them to do and convert.

Now, in your case, it seems like that you include the Attention with Action together and with this way the user/visitor is confused. *(I refer to the first section)*
Also, I believe that there is no specific reason for adding the email field at the bottom of the page and clicking on "get started" goes to the form again. I feel like that with this way you tell to your visitor to "read your story" again.

Whatever it is, maybe you will need to consider all of these cases with real A/B testing.

Comment: Thank you so much for this @vbaimas. This was so helpful and also now i have a better understanding of the flow. :)